# CaseArticle creates duplicate IDs and points to incorect KAV ID, after VersionHistory is saved with a null VersionID

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge

I am creating a Scheduled Apex function to update Case fields when a Knowledge Article is attached.  I would like to display the Article Title and Article Number.  To do this, I am using a query to CaseArticle:

```
Select CreatedDate, CaseId, KnowledgeArticleId, KnowledgeArticleVersionId, KnowledgeArticle.ArticleNumber, KnowledgeArticleVersion.Title, Case.CaseNumber from CaseArticle where CreatedDate >= :StartTime and CreatedDate <= :EndTime
```

However, I encountered a bug in how **CaseArticle** records are created after a **Article_Type__VersionHistory** record is saved with a null `VersionId`.

Based on **Article_Type__VersionHistory** records some articles are being saved with a null `VersionId`.  These happens when `EventType = created`, or on `KavRevised`.

When **VersionHistory** is saved with a null `VersionId` the code that generates **CaseArticle** records creates two records with the same CaseArticle `ID`.  The only difference in the two records is two different `KAV IDs`.  One points to a valid KAV record, the other doesn't exist.

In our case, this causes problems because the null `KAV ID` tends to be created second.  Since the records have the same CaseArticle `ID`, the null `KAV ID` overwrites the valid ID when CaseArticle IDs are used to populate a Map (without logic to check first whether the KAV Id points to a valid record).

This bug also impacts the SF Development Console when the query to CaseArticle includes the Id field.  The SFDC apparently will not display duplicate `IDs`, so only the last duplicate is shown, which is typically the incorrect `KAV ID`.  When the query does not include `ID`, all records are shown.

**Here are examples from Data Loader:**
[image: CaseArticle error creating duplicate Ids and links to non-existent KAV Ids]

**Error Behavior after CaseArticle creates duplicate records**

- Once CaseArticle creates duplicate records for an Article Version, it continues to do so even after the VersionHistory shows the new KAV ID in later revisions.
- I do not have any examples where a new version of an article already creating duplicate CaseArticle records has been published to see if this continues to later versions.  But it does for revisions to the same version.
- In one case, VersionHistory shows a null Version ID through nine revision cycles *after* CaseArticle has started creating duplicate records.  On the 10th revision, it finally shows the same KAV ID set in CaseArticle for that version.
- In one other case, VersionHistory shows a null Version ID, but CaseArticle links to a single KAV ID for that version, and does not create duplicate records.
- While there are two exceptions listed, almost all other instances follow the pattern listed above.

Comment: What do you mean invalid? They both have the same prefix? It looks like one of them may point to a deleted version, perhaps...but it's hard to say until you **[edit]** your post to clarify.

Comment: I said invalid because a search for the record showing a null title (ka2600000004JWiAAM) returns zero results in KnowledgeArticleVersion, while a search for the other (ka260000000PDk8AAG) returns results.  I tried different queries on KnowledgeArticleVersion and KnowledgeArticle and cannot find any reference to the former ID except in CaseArticle.

Comment: Don't filter your KAV query against the `Title`, just the `Id`. Note that you have to query the specific article type, e.g. `SELECT Title FROM Article_Type__kav WHERE Id = 'kA2...'`. You can get the specific article type if you don't know it by doing an anonymous script: `system.debug(Id.valueOf('kA2'.rightPad(15, '0')).getSObjectType());`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Adrian.  I'm filtering CaseArticle by CreatedDate to get all updates in a date range.  I then create sets of IDs for KnowledgeArticle, KnowledgeArticleVersion, and Case objects and query each by ID to create maps.  Most articles have a KAV Id that doesn't link to a KAV record and shows Null Titles.

I will make a reply with query results to better explain.  When my CaseArticle SoQL query includes the 'Id' field, most KAVs are null.  When I don't include 'Id' every Null KAV has a different KAV that isn't null.